# image gallery with flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox, gallery

I want to make a small flexbox gallery of images with inconsistent height.

Desired result using grid:

[image: Images aligned properly]

Current result with flexbox:

[image: Images aligned improperly].

This content belongs to a course, but I want to do that part with flexbox, as a learning method

```css
container {
  width: 90%;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1200px;
  padding: 80px 0;
}

.projects {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 500px;
}

.projects__grid {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: space-between;
  height: 550px;
  background-color: aqua;
}

.projects__item {
  width: 32.8%;
  height: 270px;
}

.projects__item--first {
  height: 550px;
}

.projects__img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center;
}
```

```html
<section class="projects">
  <div class="container">
    <h2 class="subtitle">mis proyectos</h2>

    <div class="projects__grid">
      <article class="projects__item projects__item--first">
        <img src="assets/img1.jpg" alt="" class="projects__img">
      </article>

      <article class="projects__item">
        <img src="assets/img2.jpg" alt="" class="projects__img">
      </article>

      <article class="projects__item">
        <img src="assets/img3.jpg" alt="" class="projects__img">
      </article>

      <article class="projects__item">
        <img src="assets/img4.jpg" alt="" class="projects__img">
      </article>

      <article class="projects__item">
        <img src="assets/img5.jpg" alt="" class="projects__img">
      </article>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Please upload the images using a site like imgur, and get them working in the snippet

Comment: Your desired result will only be possible with more HTML containers as flexbox can only work in one axis at a time. Recommended viewing: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hs3piaN4b5I

Comment: um ok, so in this case it can't be done with flexbox, because I need to align on two axes, I already looked at the code with grid and it comes out easy. Thank you very much for taking the time to reply.